# How do I shift a series of time lapsed photos (a week between each photo) to match hardpoints?

Tags: post-processing

I have collected a series of photos approximately 1 week apart using a drone. Thus, the photos are slightly different.  I want to transform each photo using a series of hard points so that those points align. I don't want to merge the photos, just align all of the photos so that they don't "jump" around when I toggle through them. I assume I choose a base photo that I'll match the others to and then crop them all to have the same frame size.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely use [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Align_a_stack_of_photos.html) for this.

Hugin comes with an `align_image_stack` script that processes everything automatically, but this isn't always what you want.

If you want a bit more control, in the "Photos" tab, set the "Feature matching" to `Align image stack`. You can then click "Create control points" to let Hugin compute them for you (and then remove the troublesome ones, for instance hose set on moving objects: planes, birds, people, vehicles, leaves...). You can also add them manually.

Comment: I downloaded Hugin but haven't been able to shift the photo without merging the images.  Hugin is not the easiest software to figure out.  Can Hugin actually transform the image without stacking them?

Comment: @GeorgeThompson See augmented answer.